# Getting error with derive_stream function of OpenSTARS R package

Tags: r, grass

I'm  trying to derive a stream network using the `OpenSTARS` R package with the command `derive_stream()` but I'm facing with this error:

> Conditioning DEM ...
> Error in system(cmd0, intern = TRUE) : 'r.hydrodem.exe' not found
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: Package rgrass7 transitioning to package rgrass for GRASS 7+.
> Error in parseGRASS(cmd, legacyExec = legacyExec) : r.hydrodem not found

I think this error comes from the underlying function `execGRASS("r.hydrodem")` that is not able to find `r.hydrodem.exe`.

I honestly do not understand the reason of this error. The addon is installed in my GRASS GIS, and when I try to run the "r.hydrodem" command in GRASS GIS it works perfectly fine.
I'm working on a Windows 10 machine with R version 4.2.1 and GRASS GIS version 8.2.

Has anyone else encountered this error or have any suggestions? Thanks.